# Chapter 9 automate the boring stuff with python

Tags: python

Been using this quarantine to learn Python and after trying this by myself and looking for info online i don't know what's wrong with my code, as it returns nothing even though i have no error after compiling, just blank results. Program does look for fyles of more than 100Mb on the specified folder and return the names of those.

```
import os

folder = os.path.abspath(input('Please enter folder to search for files larger than 100MB:\n'))

def get_MB(value):
    MB = 1 * (10**6)
    my_MB = value * MB
    return my_MB

size_input = input('Enter your desired minimun MB: ')
my_min = get_MB(size_input)

for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in filenames:
        file_path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(foldername), filename)
        size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
        if size >= my_min:
            print(filename)
```

Comment: Running this, I get `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'` because you didn't convert `size_input` to an int.

Comment: Didn't you get an error? Are you maybe using Python 2, which didn't raise one when comparing strings and integers? If this is the case, you should really switch to Python 3, Python 2 is no longer supported.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille But on Python 2 `input` does return an `int` since it basically uses `eval(raw_input())`.

Comment: After changing to `size_input = int(input('Enter your desired minimun MB: '))` and looking for files above 1 MB, your code works perfectly for me...

Comment: No error no, i'm currently using Python 3.7 running it from spyder.

Comment: @leprinx Then the only explanation is that your `folder` is empty.

Comment: Please check that the version of Python you run really is 3.7: just add `import sys; print(sys.version)` at the top of your script.

Comment: You are right, i have to use and int converter for the input but even entering 0 as the min size i get a blank response, does not print anything

Comment: changed it to os.getcwd and it works just fine, will check why the specified path is empty.. that was it. By writing desktop it doesnt work

Comment: i did the sys thing, that's the result:

Comment: 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: @leprinx Most certainly `desktop` is not a valid path. The path is taken relative to your working directory and even if you were sitting at `../Desktop` it's still spelled with a capital `D`. Note that when the directory is not available, `os.walk` will just yield nothing.

Comment: but i thought using os.path.abspath(Desktop) i was able to use it in the os.walk function folder = os.path.abspath(input('Please enter folder to search for files larger than 100MB:\n'))

Comment: what should i do to convert the str that the username gives me to use in os.walk() ?

Comment: @leprinx This requires that you have a folder named `Desktop` *inside* your current working directory (`os.getcwd()`). I suppose you don't? Where do you run the script? What's the output of `os.getcwd()`? Or better, just `print(folder)` and verify it actually exists.

Answer (score -1):

Convert the size_input to int/float when doing calc:

```
def get_MB(value):
    MB = 1 * (10**6)
    my_MB = int(value) * MB
    return my_MB
```

Because your get_mb function returns the value 10**6 times as a very long string and not a value of type int. Therefore `typeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: Thanksa lot! that was one of the two problems indeed. Only thing now is it reads the input folder as a blank folder, if i type desktop i get no result but if i change the os.walk to os.walk(get.cwd()) it goes just fine